Experience editor not opening in sitecore9.3(SXA)
I have sitecore 9.3, sxa, while opening any pages in experience editor it keeps on loading, this is in my local instance, and below is the error what i am getting
<!-- 
    [InvalidOperationException]: siteName
       at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetCookieValue(String siteName, String key, String defaultValue)
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_WebEditMode()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.AddRendering.CanAddRendering.GetControlState()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.ExecuteProcessComponentState[T](Object requestObject, T context)
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.ExecuteProcessComponentState(Object requestObject)
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.GetProcessComponentState()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.PreRender()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonIconButtonBase.PreRender()
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickbarButton.ControlsExtension.QuickbarButton(Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
       at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickbarButton_QuickbarButton_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93.cm.dev.local\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickbarButton\QuickbarButton.cshtml:line 4
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
    [InvalidOperationException]: Error while rendering view: &#39;/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickbarButton/QuickbarButton.cshtml&#39; (model: &#39;Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc&#39;).
    
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action)
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter output, Item item)
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.QuickBar.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.ControlsExtension.QuickBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
       at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickBar_QuickBar_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93.cm.dev.local\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickBar\QuickBar.cshtml:line 4
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
    [InvalidOperationException]: Error while rendering view: &#39;/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickBar/QuickBar.cshtml&#39; (model: &#39;Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc&#39;).
    
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
       at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
       at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)
       at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93.cm.dev.local\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
    [InvalidOperationException]: Error while rendering view: &#39;/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml&#39; (model: &#39;Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc&#39;).
    
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
       at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
    [InvalidOperationException]: Error while rendering view: &#39;/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml&#39; (model: &#39;Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc&#39;).
    
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    [HttpUnhandledException]: An unhandled exception occurred.
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
       at (Object , Object )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
    -->



This issues generally occurs in any of these two scenarios.

Check the Preview.DefaultSite setting point to one of the website defined in your solution.



Check the default site website inside sites node within the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx, exist within your solution.

In any of the two scenarios, this issue occurs. You can check the showconfig.aspx to resolve the issue.
Hope this helps!!!
